# How to find if you're facing a certain location in Android?

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I've searched online but haven't yet found anything like this. Basically, is there a way where I can know if I'm facing a certain location.

For example, I have my current location in latitude & longitude and I have a second location in latitude & longitude. Now I want to know when the second location is directly in front of me as I turn.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer my apologies. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume that you mean the phone is "facing" the location of interest, and you already know which axis will determine this. What I would do is use the [`SensorManager.getOrientation(float\[\], float\[\])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])) to get the radians of where you device is facing, then convert it into degrees.

Next, I would ensure I get an accurate and current point from the device (GPS, not Network), and call [`Location.bearingTo(Location)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo(android.location.Location)) on the location from the device with the destination location as the parameter to get the degrees to it.

Finally, I would compare the two results and determine if the device is "facing", within a certain range. This might have to be adjusted based on how far the destination is from the current location, but I would experiment with this a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I don't know which axis will determine this. Could you enlighten me please? Thanks so much!

Comment: Use this link as a reference for the phone's coordinate system (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords). If you want the back of the phone to face the second location, that would be the negative Z-axis, for example.

Comment: Great! Would this comparison be done using a simple if statement? `if (-zaxis == bearing)`? Thanks a lot, I really appreciate all the help. I'm very new to all this so am a little confused at the moment, especially with the Android documentation!

Comment: Also, my `Location.bearingTo(location)` always returns a number like `-0.143435`. Could I use `Math.toDegrees(bearing)` to make it into degrees? Thanks

Comment: For you first question, probably not. I'd try to figure out a range to compare it to. As for the second question, that is in degrees East of true North, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can predict your direction/location if you use Android location Manager. Take a look at this [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)

Comment: I've already been able to get the current location. Now I have a second location, and I want to be able to know when I am facing in the direction of that second location

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this help, but you could take a look at the Places API from Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses

The response has an attribute called viewport that with some processing can help you

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this isn't helpful for me in this situation.